# vba power point : how to change the selected text in table cell in powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have selected the text in table cell of powerpoint as below picture shows
[table in powerpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvNTC.png)

when I run the vba sub which is as below

```
Sub changeSelectedText()
    Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
    Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation
    Dim text As String
    text = "cell content change"
    selectionType = ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Type
    ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.text = text


End Sub
```

the error occured on the line: ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.text = text

so I can not change the selected text in the table cell of powerpoint.

Comment: the title is : vba powerpoint: how to change the selected text in table cell in the powerpoint?

Comment: What is the specific error message you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

If your code will run from within PowerPoint itself, this works:

```
Sub changeSelectedText()

    Dim text As String
    text = "cell content change"
    ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.text = text

End Sub
```

If you're driving PPT from another app, try this for starters.  Aircode.  Untested. Caveat computor:

```
Sub changeSelectedText()
    Dim ppapp as object
    Dim pppres as Object
    Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
    Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation
    Dim text As String
    text = "cell content change"
    ' You haven't declared selectionType and don't
    ' use it for anything, so I've commented it out
    ' selectionType = ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Type
    ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.text = text

End Sub
```

Comment: when I run the above vba program  error occured" the value out of the range" at the line,  ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.text = text. The selected text is in the table cell of the powerpoint.

Comment: Which platform (PC or Mac) and what version of PPT do you have?